# Dependencies error while installing ImageMagick with rpm on amazonlinux docker image

Tags: python, docker, dependencies, imagemagick

I have been trying to resolve the dependencies issues since two days. So I am trying to build the docker image using amazonlinux as a base image. I want to install ImageMagick. When I use yum install it installs the version 6.7.8, which installs properly but this is not the version I want. I specifically want 6.9.9 version. I have downloaded the rpm file and trying to install the ImageMagick rpm and ImageMagick-devel rpm using the below command.

`RUN rpm -Uvh --nodeps ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64.rpm ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64.rpm`

But even after installing both imagemagick and imagemagick-devel, i am running into dependencies error. This is really frustating!

```
:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libICE.so.6()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libSM.so.6()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libX11.so.6()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libXext.so.6()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libXt.so.6()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libfftw3.so.3()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libfontconfig.so.1()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libfreetype.so.6()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libgomp.so.1()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of liblcms2.so.2()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libltdl.so.7()(64bit)
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of /usr/bin/pkg-config
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of OpenEXR-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of bzip2-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of freetype-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of jasper-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of lcms2-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libX11-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libXext-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libXt-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libgs-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libjpeg-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libtiff-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of libwebp-devel
1:ImageMagick-devel-6.9.9.38-1.fc28.x86_64 has missing requires of pkgconfig
```

Please note I am not trying to install the latest imagicmagick 7 as it is not compatible with wand, i am trying to install this particular 6.9.9 version. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I do not know much about installing on Amazon, but why do you have --nodeps in your install. I would expect that means do not install any dependencies. And your error messages are showing that you are missing a lot of dependencies. Try removing --nodeps and compile again.

Comment: No luck! Still running into dependencies error. When I manually try to install those dependencies it gives more error. Just an infinity of errors!!

Comment: Sorry, I do not know much about Amazon docker

Answer (score 0):

I used another image altogether which is fedora:rawhide. It contains latest python3 and latest ImageMagick. For my service, i needed the latest one and amazonlinux did not have the latest ImageMagick which was why I was manually installing using rpm. I used the fedora image and now i can just use yum install ImageMagick and yum install ImageMagick-devel and the problem is resolved.

Comment: Is this an answer? If so, did it work. Was it the image problem or the ImageMagick or Python issue? Please clarify. Your post is not very clear and should include more details why it worked.